# $.getJSON's success function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a .json file with this line:

```
$.getJSON('engines.json',{},function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

If I look in firebug, it says the file is loaded. But the success function never runs. It happens with $.get as well.

Comment: can you show us your test page?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think that the JSON not validating was the issue. Fixed.

Comment: Just remember: the `success` function will only be called if the JSON request is successful and if it validates :)

Comment: FYI, you can also do `$.getJSON("engines.json", {dataKey:dataValue}).success(function(rt, st, xhr){ /* do work */ })` or it might be `$.getJSON("engines.json", {dataKey:dataValue}).complete(function(rt, st, xhr){ /* do work */ })`, i dont remember exactly but i know its one of those

Comment: Have you included the api (<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
)for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `JSON` file you are requesting for, it is actually **well formatted** and **valid**.

You can validate your `JSON` file/response using this online validator: http://jsonlint.com/